# Implementing function for reuse?

Tags: java

Suppose I have two methods

```
public void doStuffOne(int a, char b, String c){
 // individual logic
  SomeBuilder builder = new SomeBuilder();
  builder.setSomeField(helperFunction(() -> someFieldGeneratorForStuffOne(a, b, c)));
}

public void doStuffTwo(long external, int a, char b, String c){
 // individual logic
  SomeBuilder builder = new SomeBuilder();
  builder.setSomeField(helperFunction(() -> someFieldGeneratorForStuffTwo(external, a, b, c)));
}
```

Here are the generators:
**Note:** None of this code requires multi threading, its all synchronous and simple code.

```
public SomeField someFieldGeneratorForStuffOne(int a, char b, String c){
 // ..
}

public SomeField someFieldGeneratorForStuffTwo(long external, int a, char b, String c){
 // ..
}
```

Here is the helper function they call:

```
public SomeField helperFunction(Runnable someFieldGenerator){
  // do some logic common to both doStuffOne and doStuffTwo
   return someFieldGenerator.run(); // This will call the function passed in
}
```

I'm wondering whats the best way to approach this. `Runnable` doesnt return and brings in multithreading into the picture which is not needed at all.

Basically I just need an easy way to pass in my method that I want to run and just run it simply as if it was a normal helper being invoked.

Whats the best approach in Java 8?

Comment: "*(A) Runnable doesnt return (B) and brings in multithreading into the picture*" A) So use `Supplier` B) no it doesn't

Comment: @Michael, could you point me to some examples or Docs for `Supplier`?

Comment: Google "Java supplier" and it's the first result.